# What's the common practice for enums in Python?

Tags: python, enums

How can I implement an *enumeration type* (spelled `enum` in some languages) in Python? What is the common practice to get this functionality?

Comment: Now there is a standard Enum type in Python 3.4. Read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653129/future-compatible-enums-in-2-7

Comment: Here is the PEP for the enum type that is now in Python: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/

Answer (score 374, accepted):

```
class Materials:
    Shaded, Shiny, Transparent, Matte = range(4)

>>> print Materials.Matte
3
```

### Update: For Python 3.4+:

As of Python 3.4+, you can now use `Enum` (or `IntEnum` for enums with `int` values) from the [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module. Use [`enum.auto`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.auto) to increment the values up automatically:

```py
import enum


class Materials(enum.IntEnum):
    Shaded = 1
    Shiny = enum.auto()
    Transparent = 3
    Matte = enum.auto()


print(Materials.Shiny == 2)  # True
print(Materials.Matte == 4)  # True
```

Comment: I haven't seen that one before, good stuff.

Comment: The only problem is I need the first item to be 1. Is that possible to do with your method?

Comment: Of all the methods i've seen, this is probably my favorite. Very elegant!

Comment: @Joan You could do `_unused, Shaded, Shiny, Transparent, Matte = range(5)`

Comment: Kinda late, but you can also do `Shaded, Shiny, Transparent, Matte = range(1, 5)` if you don't like having the `_unused` there

Comment: You also don't have to use range, assigning each class variable a value individually.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method of making an enum is incomplete, as the enums cannot be iterated over, nor is each value an unique type (e.g. just an int).

Comment: @Gewthen In many languages, enums are "just an int". Isn't that more or less expected? If necessary, you could implement an appropriate [iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/1796585).

Comment: @MadsY In other languages they are simply syntactic sugar, whereas in other languages (e.g. Python3) they are not. Having a strong type for your values is generally better in strongly types languages, because it utilizes the language more. If they are only just numbers it's more to remember when debugging or looking at logs. I'd rather just see `Materials.shinny` in a log than `1` because `1` tells me much less than `Materials.shinny`

Comment: This should be updated to add that `enums` are in Python as of 3.4

Answer (score 21):

I've seen this pattern several times:

```
>>> class Enumeration(object):
        def __init__(self, names):  # or *names, with no .split()
            for number, name in enumerate(names.split()):
                setattr(self, name, number)

>>> foo = Enumeration("bar baz quux")
>>> foo.quux
2
```

You can also just use class members, though you'll have to supply your own numbering:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
        bar  = 0
        baz  = 1
        quux = 2

>>> Foo.quux
2
```

If you're looking for something more robust (sparse values, enum-specific exception, etc.), [try this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/67107/).

Answer (score 9):

I have no idea why Enums are not support natively by Python.
The best way I've found to emulate them is by overridding _ str _ and _ eq _ so you can compare them and when you use print() you get the string instead of the numerical value.

```
class enumSeason():
    Spring = 0
    Summer = 1
    Fall = 2
    Winter = 3
    def __init__(self, Type):
        self.value = Type
    def __str__(self):
        if self.value == enumSeason.Spring:
            return 'Spring'
        if self.value == enumSeason.Summer:
            return 'Summer'
        if self.value == enumSeason.Fall:
            return 'Fall'
        if self.value == enumSeason.Winter:
            return 'Winter'
    def __eq__(self,y):
       return self.value==y.value
```

Usage:

```
>>> s = enumSeason(enumSeason.Spring)

>>> print(s)

Spring
```

Comment: PEP354 has a rejection notice.  See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0354/#rejection-notice

Comment: It would be quicker to have a class dictionary {"Spring": 0, "Summer":1, ...} and use __init__ to iterate through entries and set attributes, because then __str__ could just look the value up rather than being coded by hand for every case.

Comment: See this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/

Answer (score 6):

You could probably use an inheritance structure although the more I played with this the dirtier I felt.

```
class AnimalEnum:
  @classmethod
  def verify(cls, other):
    return issubclass(other.__class__, cls)


class Dog(AnimalEnum):
  pass

def do_something(thing_that_should_be_an_enum):
  if not AnimalEnum.verify(thing_that_should_be_an_enum):
    raise OhGodWhy
```