# Least unofficial enum support in python2.7 - flufl.enum or enum34?

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

Never thought I'd need to do this, but here I am intending to use enums in python 2.7.

There is Barry's [flufl.enum](http://packages.python.org/flufl.enum/docs/using.html) which PEP 435 says "...was the reference implementation upon which this PEP was originally based".

But there is also a backport [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) on pypi.

**These both seem semi-official, so which one should I use in new code?**

"There should be one obvious way to do it", but it's a hard topic to google for because there are dozens (hundreds?) of hand-rolled implementations out there.  And the python 3.4 enum is still just a release candidate.

I've tried out both `flufl.enum.Enum` and `enum34.Enum`, and the behaviour is quite different - most notably the differing semantics of `__getitem__`.  According to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653129/future-compatible-enums-in-2-7/21394224#comment23954299_16653129) by Martijn Pieters, backport is/was challenging because implementation relies on the new `__prepare__` function on the metaclass.  I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932/674039) post and the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) in entirety.

Comment: also see: http://packages.python.org/flufl.enum/docs/using.html#differences-from-pep-354

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)
 matches what is in [Python3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), so that's the one to use.

The one big difference between the backport and 3.4's:

- In Python 2 you cannot get definition order (because `__prepare__` doesn't exist yet), but there is a work-around -- define `_order_` and it will be the "definition order" in Python 2 (it's simply ignored in Python 3).  If you don't use the workaround the order used is the values of the members, in increasing order.

**Update**

- the preferred spelling is now `_order_` (single instead of double leading and trailing underscores)
- Python3.6+ will check that `_order_` matches the actual order (useful for keeping Python 2/3 code in sync)

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)
, and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.