# What does enum() do in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, enumeration, enumerate

I understand that enum is a class I can inherit from to make my class iterable over the objects.

But what does enum() function do, as shown in this code snippet below?

```
enums = [enum(domain, [], q=subdomains_queue, silent=silent, verbose=verbose) for enum in chosenEnums]
for enum in enums:
    enum.start()
for enum in enums:
    enum.join()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702834/whats-the-common-practice-for-enums-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python and https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enum` is not a class you can inherit from; `Enum` in the `enum` module is (see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)).

The `enum()` in the code you are describing is a callable object that has previously been put into the list `chosenEnums`. We can't tell you what it is, or does, without the rest of the code.